# How to express feelings about a performed action?

Tags: verbs, past

I am wondering how I express my feelings about an action that has already occurred/been performed.

For example, how would I state the following:

- I am happy to have returned home.
- I am sad that I missed the train.
- I am upset that I finished the apples.

My best guess for the first example is the following:
帰った【かえった】ことが嬉しい【うれしい】。

However, I am unsure about my usage of こと. If it is correct are there other ways of writing this kind of sentence that I should be aware of?

I know that の is also used for verb nominalisation but as far as I could find online that would be wrong since the two actions are being performed at different points in time, right?

Comment: what are your attempts at forming these sentences with those sentiments?

Comment: My best attempt at the first one is:
帰ったことが嬉しい。

But I'm not sure if I'm using こと correctly in this context; I'm also a little unsure of my usage of the word 帰る but that's a different issue.

Even if that is correct, are there other ways of phrasing it that I should be aware of?

Comment: @JonathanDiGiacomo Please incorporate your attempts into your question otherwise people would think it a simple translation request.

Comment: @broccoliforest sorry for failing to do that originally. I can see how my question sounded like a translation request.

Comment: [Te-form for reason](http://www.learn-japanese-adventure.com/te-form-cause-reason.html) works fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, your use of ～た + こと construction is correct. You can express the sentiment about an event that happened in the **past** at the moment of feeling.

- 家に帰れ**た［こと／の］**‌がうれしい。
  <sup>*Equivalent of "happy that --" is typically expressed with potential form, especially for the action of yourself.</sup>
- 電車を逃【の】がし**た［こと／の］**‌が残念だ。
- りんごを全部食べてしまっ**たこと**にうろたえている。

However, the sentiment toward **what has (just) happened** is simply described with the successive function of te-form.

- 家に帰れ**て**うれしい。
- 電車を逃がし（てしまっ）**て**残念だ。
- りんごを全部食べてしまっ**て**うろたえている。

Comment: `"happy that V"` は happy that SV か happy to V じゃなくて・・？

Comment: @Chocolate そうですよね。それから、「たことが＋形容詞」と「て＋形容詞」と、どちらが有り勝ちでしょうか。「て」の方が、聞くことが良くありますが、「たこと」というのは聞いたことないと思います。。。

Comment: @Chocolate ほんとですね。SVのつもりだったのですが動詞のことしか考えてませんでしたw

Comment: @Rightleg 回答の通り、二つの表現の間にはニュアンスの差があるので、いつでも交換して使えるわけではありません。よく使われるのは「て」の方だと思います。

Answer (score 3):

> How to express feelings about a performed action?
>
> I am happy to have returned home.
>   I am sad that I missed the train.
>   I am upset that I finished the apples.

帰ったことが嬉しい is not wrong, but we don't really say it.

I think what you are looking for is ～**して**よかった, or ～**できて**うれしい.
This is the way we say it.

帰れて良かった, literally saying "It's good that I've been able to have come back."

電車に乗り遅れて悲しい。乗れなくて残念。It seems it's always natural to say ～して悲しい, ～してがっかり, ～できなくて残念。

食べてしまって自分が腹立たしい。
mm.. more realistically, it might be 食べてしまった。悲しい。